# Navigation goal offset

Tags: ros, navigation, base-global-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the default navigation with *TrajectoryPlannerROS* and the *global_planner*. I realized that the robot never really reaches its exact goal. So I assume there is a certain threshhold, like an offset in which the robot needs to be from the actual goal.
My question is: **How can I set this offset?** (If there is one)
The problem I have is, that the robot often rotates a lot next to the goal, which I think is due to this offset being to small.
Thanks for your help! :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199184/navigation-goal-offset/) by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on ROS Answers with karma: 862 on 2014-12-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://wiki.ros.org/base_local_planner?distro=indigo#Goal_Tolerance_Parameters

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2014-12-09**:
That is actually quite embarrassing. I really am aware of the parameters of the local planner. I just was not able to find those particular ones before. Sorry for that.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-12-10**:
No need to be embarrassed. Just be sure to click the checkmark.